# Can the bgcolor attribute be passed to a pop-up window?

Tags: javascript

I have the code below to open a pop-up window which works fine. The pop-up has a black background controlled within the body tag of the code in the pop-up itself.

When the pop-up initially opens, the page has a white background then goes black once the code loads. This doesn't bother me but it does bother my client!

So, is there a way that I can pass the `bgcolor` color attribute to the pop-up from the javascript that is on the parent page, so that the pop-up is immediately black when it opens. I hope that makes sense!

**Here is my current code:**

```
// START OF POP UP ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}

// END OF POP UP ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="PopupCenter('page.asp', 'myPop1',678,550);" class="staffBioLinks">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By using something like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    var targetWin = window.open ('about:blank', title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    targetWin.document.body.style.backgroundColor='#000';
    targetWin.location.href=pageURL;
}
</script>
```

You open a blank page, then you set the background color first then redirect to the URL you want to load. During the loading time, the page is black (in my example).

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: I tried it on IE 9 and Safari 5.1.4 and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, just noticed I still get a flash of white in IE. Is there anything else that can be done to resolve this in IE? I have very limited programming knowledge but I'd guess there isn't! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the best thing you can do for IE, I guess. Besides, most users already use Chrome or Firefox and a [government has even already urged the public to stop using it](http://news.yahoo.com/microsoft-warns-internet-explorer-security-flaw-031807045--sector.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could do so as a query string.  If you can get the value then it should be as easy as appending it to the end of the page URL.

`page.asp` would be `page.asp?bgColor=xxxxxx`

You can handle the response on the other side of the pop-up however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
targetWin.document.bgColor = 'lightgreen';
targetWin.focus();
```